# Event handlers in a separate class Axon 3.0.3

Tags: java, spring-boot, axon

I've got a fairly simple CQRS setup here using Axon & Spring.

This is the configuration class.

```
@AnnotationDriven
@Configuration
public class AxonConfig {

    @Bean
    public EventStore eventStore() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandBus commandBus() {
        return new SimpleCommandBus();
    }

    @Bean
    public EventBus eventBus() {
        return new SimpleEventBus();
    }
}
```

This is my Aggregate...

```
@Aggregate
public class ThingAggregate {
    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String id;

    public ThingAggregate() {
    }

    public ThingAggregate(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public handle(CreateThingCommand cmd) {
        apply(new ThingCreatedEvent('1234', cmd.getThing()));
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(ThingCreatedEvent event) {
        // this is called!
    }
}
```

This is my EventHandler in a separate .java file...

```
@Component
public class ThingEventHandler {

    private ThingRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public ThingEventHandler(ThingRepository thingRepository) {
        this.repository = conditionRepository;
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void handleThingCreatedEvent(ThingCreatedEvent event) {
        // this is only called if I publish directly to the EventBus
        // apply within the Aggregate does not call it!
        repository.save(event.getThing());
    }
}
```

I'm using the CommandGateway to send the original creation command. My CommandHandler in the Aggregate receives the command fine, but when I call `apply` within my Aggregate, passing a new Event, my EventHandler in the external class, does not get called. Only EventHandlers directly inside the Aggregate class are called.

If I try and publish an Event directly to the EventBus, my external EventHandler is called.

Any idea why my EventHandler in an external java class is not being called when I call `apply` within the Aggregate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Axon 3, the Event Store is a *replacement* for the Event Bus. It is basically a specialized implementation that doesn't only forward events to subscribed, but also stores them.

In your configuration, you have both an Event Bus and an Event Store. The Aggregate's events are probably published to the Event Store. Since you receive events in your handler when publishing directly to the Event Bus, your handlers are subscribed there.

The solution: remove the Event Bus from your configuration and use the Event Store exclusively.